# How to keep filter values after successful login redirect

Tags: javascript, react-admin

I'm looking for a way to keep filter values and the rest of query string after user is authenticated.

In my app I use [custom login page](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html#customizing-the-login-and-logout-components) to handle external ID provider. When unauthenticated user comes to the app e.g from `domain.com/#/my-component?filter=%7B%22filterA%22%3A%22foo%22%2C%22filterB%22%3A%22bar%22%7D&order=ASC&page=1&perPage=10&sort=foo`, the user is redirected to `/#/login` page where user is logged in successfully and then redirected back to `domain.com/#/my-component` but **without query string**. I used `useLogin()` hook but I can't figure out how to keep the rest of params.

Is it something that exists in react-admin but I forgot to use or I should implement memorizing query string by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue which I fixed myself. The fix is coming in version 3.14.4